# jQuery called with setInterval isn't animating on first interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, setinterval

I have two images stacked. With setInterval(), the top one fades away, exposing the second. Then the top image switches to the bottom's src while invisible, and becomes opaque again. The second image changes to the next image and waits for the setInterval() to fade the top image and do it all over again.

It all works great, except the first time around; There's no fade. What am I not seeing?

This happens on all firefox and chrome and I assume all others.

HTML

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval('swapImage()', 5000);
    var galleryCount = 3;   
    </script>

    ...

    <img id="image" src="images/gallery/01.jpg" />
    <img id="imagenext" src="images/gallery/02.jpg" />
```

Javascript

```
function swapImage(imageToFadeID)
{
    $("#image").animate
    (
        { "opacity": "0" },
        "slow",
        "linear",
        changeImage()
    );
};

var i = 1;

function changeImage()
//counter +1
{
i = i + 1;
//add "0" to image number "j" if less than 10.
if (i < 10)
    {
    var j = "0" + i;
    }
else
    {
    j = i;
    }
//change top image to match bottom
var topImage = document.getElementById("imagenext").src;
document.getElementById("image").src = topImage;
//make top image reappear
document.getElementById("image").style.opacity = '1';
//change out bottom image to next
var btmImage = "images/gallery/" + j + ".jpg";
document.getElementById("imagenext").src = btmImage;
//reset counter if at end
if (i > galleryCount - 1)
    {
    i = 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks like you're invoking `changeImage` instead of passing it as a callback to `animate`:

Wrong:

```
function swapImage(imageToFadeID)
{
    $("#image").animate
    (
        { "opacity": "0" },
        "slow",
        "linear",
        changeImage()   // <--- !!! Remove the parentheses from this line!
    );
};
```

---

Right:

```
function swapImage(imageToFadeID)
{
    $("#image").animate
    (
        { "opacity": "0" },
        "slow",
        "linear",
        changeImage
    );
};
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks! Why can't you use the paranthesis in the complete function? Does that mess up the syntax? What if I needed to use a variable there?

Comment: With parentheses it's a function call - `changeImage` gets invoked and only its return value gets handed to the animate function. Without parentheses it's just the function itself - you hand that to animate(), the animation gets performed and when it's complete animate() invokes that function you passed.

Comment: If you need to pass arguments to changeImage, wrap another function around that: `animate(..., "linar", function() { changeImage(param1, param2); });`